# OCaml insist that function is not polymorphic, but don't specify the type

Tags: ocaml

Is it possible to explicitly write down a type that's non-polymorphic but has delayed unification like underscore types?

So, OCaml will sometimes produce a type that the top-level prints with a leading underscore (e.g. `_a`) in the course of type checking. Specifically, these appear when instantiating an empty `Hashtbl.t` and under some other circumstances.

```
# Hashtbl.create 1;;
- : ('_a, '_b) Hashtbl.t = <abstr>
```

However, these types cannot be explicitly referred by the user in source code.

```
# (5: int);;
- : int = 5
# (5: 'a);;
- : int = 5
# (5: '_a);;
Error: The type variable name '_a is not allowed in programs
```

You can create an explicitly non-polymorphic function by exploiting the lack of higher-rank polymorphism in OCaml

```
# let id = snd ((), fun y -> y);;
val id : '_a -> '_a = <fun>
# (fun () -> fun y -> y) ();;
- : '_a -> '_a = <fun>
```

I'd like to be able to do something like

```
let id : <some magical type> = fun x -> x
```

and not rely on a limitation of the type system that could conceivably go away in the future.

Comment: May I ask *why* you would want to do this?

Comment: @AndreasRossberg, at the time I was writing an OCaml interface to a library written in C. The particular project in question tended to avoid using `.mli` files. In retrospect, this wasn't a great approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the fact that references are not generalizable.

```
# let id = let rx = ref [] in fun x -> rx := [x]; rx := []; x;;
val id : '_weak1 -> '_weak1 = <fun>
```

I'm thinking this property of references isn't likely to change.

I assume what you want is for this version of `id` to assume a single monomorphic type the first time it's actually used:

```
# id "yes";;
- : string = "yes"
# id;;
- : string -> string = <fun>
```

If you use this in real code, it will need to get a concrete type before the end of its module. You can't leave the weak type variable undefined or you get this error:

```
Error: The type of this expression, '_weak1 -> '_weak1,
       contains type variables that cannot be generalized
```

Answer (score 2):

The two other answers basically exploits the fact that only *values* are generalized, and so if you wrap your definition in something that is not a value, it doesn't get generalized. Hence the trick of giving it to the id function.

However, it doesn't work if you take the relaxed value restriction in account:

```
# let nil = id [] ;;
val nil : 'a list = []
```

You thus need to make sure the type variable you want doesn't appear in covariant position. In your first example, it appears on the left of the arrow, so it's fine. Otherwise, you need to make sure it works by hiding the type definition and ommiting the variance annotation.

```
module M : sig
  type 'a t
  val make : 'a list -> 'a t
end = struct
  type 'a t = 'a list
  let make x = x
end

let x = M.make []
val x : '_weak1 M.t
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Jeffrey Scofield's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50460061/ocaml-insist-that-function-is-not-polymorphic-but-dont-specify-the-type/50460362#50460362) but, in my opinion, it's better to avoid references, you can achieve the same behavior without them:

```
# let id = let id = fun x -> x in id id;;
val id : '_weak1 -> '_weak1 = <fun>
```

After that, if you need function with some other signature, for example `eq : '_weak2 -> '_weak2 -> bool`, then all you need is to implement `eq` in a normal way and pass it to `id`:

```
# let eq =
    let id = let id = fun x -> x in id id in
    let eq = (=) in (id (eq));;
val eq : '_weak2 -> '_weak2 -> bool = <fun>
```

Comment: You don't need all these contortions. `let id x = x ;; let eq = id (=) ;;` Is more than sufficient.